# Where are windows universal application registry changes saved?

Tags: windows, registry, win-universal-app, msix

I have a windows desktop application which uses the msix system with sideloading for deployment. This means that the application accesses %appdata%..\Local\Packages<packageId>_ when I try to save a file to the application's appdata folder. I have learned to deal with this quirk.

Recently I added a check to see if the application had been run already on the user's machine. The first time the application runs a shortcut is created and also conditionally displays the Terms and Conditions for use. This check looks up and subsequently sets a registry key of the form HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE<appName>.

The issue is that this seems to be sandboxed too. The checks successfully detect the first application start, and do not trigger on subsequent starts. The registry key however does not exist and is not viewable in the registry editor. I added a dword value like "uniquestringasdjkhdjkfhd" and searched for it but the registry search function did not find it.

This makes debugging really difficult as I can't test the fresh install state. I need to be able to delete this key and all its children. Does anyone know where the super secret windows universal registry is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All registry operations are redirected into special per-app registry hives. Your package can contain the following hives, visible in separate files if you extract its contents:

- Registry.dat
- User.dat
- User.Classes.dat

All the HKLM entries will go under Registry.dat file, while the per-user registry entries will go to the corresponding hives. The first time your app tries to write to one of them the operation will be redirected and a .dat file will be written under:

> %localappdata%\Packages<APPID>\SystemAppData\Helium

Read this extended [introduction guide on MSIX](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction#registry-redirections) to learn more on how apps behave inside its container.

Comment: To be more specific, I found the User.dat file at
%localappdata%\Packages\<APPID>\SystemAppData\Helium
Adding this to your answer would make it 100%  complete. Otherwise the answer links to an article that links to the docs that say "Copy-on-written to a per-user, per-app private location." Which leaves the reader with a fair bit of browsing through the related folders and trial and error before they get an actual path.